# how to solve this:$\nabla .(u+v+w)+\nabla ' .(t+h+g)=f$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider functions of real variables $u(x,y,z,x',y',z')$,$\quad$$v(x,y,z,x',y',z')$,$\quad$$w(x,y,z,x',y',z')$,$\quad$ $t(x,y,z,x',y',z')$,$\quad$$h(x,y,z,x',y',z')$,$\quad$$g(x,y,z,x',y',z')$,$\quad$$f(x,y,z,x',y',z')=e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}e^{-(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)}$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(u^2+v^2+w^2+t^2+h^2+g^2)dxdydzdx'dy'dz' = 1$

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial w}{\partial z}+\frac {\partial t}{\partial x'}+\frac {\partial h}{\partial y'}+\frac {\partial g}{\partial z'}=f$

written short-hand as $\nabla .(u+v+w)+\nabla ' .(t+h+g)=f$

Please how do I solve the PDE above?

Comment: I am not sure I get the problem. Does one need to find $u,v,w,t,h,g$ such that the sum of the divergence and '-divergence yield $f$?

Comment: @mvw yes find $u,v,w,t,h,g$ given f

Comment: The idea is to solve the pde given any $f$ that satisfy some conditions

Comment: Here is a simplification of the problem statement: Let $\vec{F} = (u,v,t,h,g)$ and $\vec{x} = (x,y,z,x',y',z')$. We can then write the problem as solving $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F} = f$ under the constraint that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^6} \|\vec{F}\|^2{\rm d}x < \infty$

Comment: One way to find solutions is to define $\vec{F} = \vec{\nabla}\phi$ and solve $\nabla^2\phi = f$. Since $f = e^{-r^2}$ where $r = \|\vec{x}\|$ ($=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+\ldots+z'^2}$ in your notation) it makes sense to look for spherical symmetric solutions. Assuming this we find $\vec{F} = \frac{2-e^{-r^2} \left(r^4+2 r^2+2\right)}{2 r^6} \vec{x}$. This should also satisfy the integral condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the solution of Poisson equation $\nabla .F= f$ :

$u=a e^{-(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)}\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'$

$v=be^{-(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)}\frac {y'-y}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'$

$w=ce^{-(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)}\frac {z'-z}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'$

similar expressions works for $t,h,g$

constants $a,b,c$ can be dterminined from the constraint.